# Providing access to another person's mail file in Notes

Tags: lotus-notes

We have a `userA` who is leaving the organization in some days. We have to assign another `userB` access to his emails, for which I assigned account delegation from userA to userB.

However, we have to disable the account 'userA' in some days.

1. Is there a way we can open his mail file once he is disabled on server?
2. Can we transfer all emails from userA to userB without sending each and every email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Disabling a user does not automatically remove his mail file. You can keep the file as long as you need it, just check the appropriate options when deleting the user. Delegation will be kept as is after deletion.
2. "Transferring" mail usually is not a best practice, but if you need to to that, you could manually mark all needed documents and Copy & Paste the documents into userBs database. This could also be done programmatically (an experienced programmer will have code for this already or will be able to write it quite quickly).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Did not knew about copy paste.